# MathFP library usage

Tags: android, java-me, floating-point

I am migrating a code from J2ME to Android. When analizing the J2ME code I found out that MathFP library is used for some float point calculations. I didn't know that library and I would like to know the following about it:

1. Why basic calculations (multiplication, division, sum, substraction) are made using MathFP library instead the normal operators (*, /, +, -)?
2. Is MathFP used nowadays? should I use the same MathFP library for my calculations in the android code? Or should I use another up-to-date library or method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked on both J2ME and Android apps.  Androids are (generally) so much better performing than the old J2ME devices,  your stuff should move right over, if you just switch to the Math. library for fancy math functions like atan2, cos, etc. and just use normal operations for * / + -

On the old J2ME devices, there was no support at all for floating point, and many devices couldn't perform any floating point basic calculations without the library.  That is just not the case on Android.

Comment: You could also say that PC's are (generally) so much better performing than Amiga's. Usually that's how it works when some devices have faster CPU's than others. ;-) The floating points were supported in CLDC1.1, so you have to go back quite a lot of years to find JavaME enabled devices that didn't support floating points.

Comment: You have to go back to yesterday morning when I was working on my J2ME app that is being used by people in Africa and India today to find those type of devices.  Still in use.  And the Amiga was an awesome platform!